# Is there any other parameter other than timeslicing in perf4j

Tags: java, log4j, perf4j

Is there any other parameter other than timeslicing in perf4j against which graph can be drawn

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**No** there is not. The x axis is always time in the graphs.